# Navigation bar tutorial

Tags: ios, navigation, nav

First, sorry for my bad English. I'm really beginner at App development and I'm doing an app with three views. 
The first and the second ones are switched by a Tab Bar (and that's all right so far). 
The first it's gonna be the only one which leads to the third view (which will be only a image) through a Navigation Bar. 
This nav bar in the first view will have one button to go to the third view, and in the third view the nav bar will have a button "back" (and here's the problem).

I'm putting a nav bar in the first view and I try to put a Nav item into it, but they don't let me! How can I do it ? I can't find a good Navigation Bar's tutorial whithout storyboard (I'm not using storyboards...).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at these two tutorials

http://fuelyourcoding.com/how-to-add-buttons-to-your-ios-app-navigation-bar/

and

http://www.idev101.com/learn/navigation_controllers.html