# Navigation bar not changing views

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigation, navbar

I'm doing an app with a Nav bar which will switch between the first and third views (the second and the first ones will be switched by a tab bar).

In the FirstViewController.h:

```
@property(strong,nonatomic) ThirdViewController *thirdViewController;
```

In the viewDidLoad method of the FirstViewController I made it:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Model"
style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(goToThirdView:)];
```

And also...

```
- (void)goToThirdView:(id)sender
{

    ThirdViewController *thirdViewController = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];

    self.thirdViewController = thirdViewController;   

    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:YES];

    [self.view removeFromSuperview];

    [self.view insertSubview:self.thirdViewController.view atIndex:0];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

My AppDelegate is looking like this:

```
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navigationController1, viewController2, nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

But it's not working, when I click in the button, nothing happens. Any idea ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's not a good idea to add another controller's view to your view without making that controller a child view controller. Why don't you use a navigation controller and push from first to third.

Comment: Actually I was following this tutorial http://fuelyourcoding.com/how-to-add-buttons-to-your-ios-app-navigation-bar/ that they suggest me in this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18788656/navigation-bar-tutorial , so I suppose I'm using a navigation controller..

Comment: That tutorial is using old methods if it uses [UIView commitAnimations] (you should use block based methods for animations). It's hard to advise you on what to do without know what your app structure is, and what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Your immediate problem though, is that you remove self.view from the superview, and then insert self.thirdViewController.view into it as a subview. But since it's not on screen any more, you won't see anything.

Comment: Oh, this method wasn't the tutorial, it was by my teacher.. I have two main views (the first and the second) and I want to switch between them with a tab bar (it's ok so far, using a tabbed application). And I want that a navigation bar push from the first to the third view (and it must have a back button in the third view), that's all... Thank you!(sorry for my English)

Comment: Then you need a navigation controller, not just a navigation bar.

Comment: But I do use a navigation controller, programmatically, with initWithRootViewController in the AppDelegate. I should do something with this ?

Comment: I don't know, probably -- I can't tell without know what all your controllers are and how they're arranged. When you use a navigation controller, you go to the next controller with pushViewController:animated:, not with the kind of code you show in goToThirdView:.

Comment: I put my AppDelegate in the description! I tried to put pushViewController:thirdViewController animated:YES in the selector instead of the goToThirdView:, but it doesn't work either..

Comment: Which controller is the goToThirdView method in? Edit your question again to show what code you have in that method now.

Comment: goToThirdView is in the FirstViewController.m I didn't change it, I just replaced it in the method of the right button:    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Model"
style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(pushViewController:thirdViewController animated:YES)];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should leave the selector for the button as goToThirdView:, but make that method look like this:

```
- (void)goToThirdView:(id)sender {

    ThirdViewController *thirdViewController = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:thirdViewController animated:YES];

}
```